# custom type always change the record, leaving it dirty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have the following custom type:

```rb
class EncryptedTextType < ActiveRecord::Type::Text
  def deserialize(encrypted_value)
    return unless encrypted_value

    Encryptor.decrypt(encrypted_value)
  end

  def serialize(plain_value)
    return unless plain_value

    Encryptor.encrypt(plain_value)
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Type.register(:encrypted_text, EncryptedTextType)
```

this works fine but always leave my record dirty. every time I load a record from the database that uses this type, it gets dirty instantly.

This is the record:

```rb
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :access_key, :encrypted_text
```

```
[1] pry(main)> organization = Organization.last
  Organization Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "organizations".* FROM "organizations" ORDER BY "organizations"."created_at" DESC, "organizations"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Organization:0x00007fe000628198
 id: "c968db2e-dd5a-4016-bf3d-d6037aff4d7b",

[2] pry(main)> organization.changed?
=> true
[3] pry(main)> organization.changes
=> {"access_key"=>["de07e...", "de07e..."]}
```

it is weird that even though the access key hasn't changed, AR still thinks it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future reference: I forgot to implement `changed_in_place?`

```rb
def changed_in_place?(raw_old_value, new_value)
  raw_old_value != serialize(new_value)
end
```

this did the trick